# Replace double consonant letters with one using sed command

Tags: unix, sed, command-line, tr

How to replace double consonants with only one letter using `sed` Linux command. Example: WILLIAM -> WILIAM. `grep -E '(.)\1+'` commands finds the words that follow two same consonants in a row pattern, but how do I replace them with only one occurrence of the letter?

I tried

```
cat test.txt | head | tr -s '[^AEUIO\n]' '?'
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: cat test.txt | head | tr -s '[^AEUIO\n]' '?' #all words in caps
 cat test.txt | head | tr -s '[^AEUIO\n]' '?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is all or nothing; it will replace all occurrences of the selected characters, regardless of context. For regex replacement, look at `sed` - you even included this in your question's tags, but you don't seem to have explored how it might be useful?

```
sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g' test.txt
```

The dot matches any character; to restrict to only consonants, change it to `[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]` or whatever makes sense (maybe extend to include upper case; perhaps include accented characters?)

The regex dialect understood by `sed` is more like the one understood by `grep` without `-E` (hence all the backslashes); though some `sed` implementations also support this option to select the POSIX extended regular expression dialect.

Neither `sed` not `tr` need `cat` to read standard input for them (though `tr` obscurely does not accept a file name argument). See tangentially also [Useless use of cat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Good details.. although would strictly fail requirements on “good”.

Answer (score 2):

Match one consonant, remember it in `\( \)`, then match is again with `\1` and substitute it for itself.

```
sed 's/\([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVXZ]\)\1/\1/'
```